# Integers/expressions as names for elements in lists

Tags: r, list

I am trying to understand names, lists and lists of lists in R. It would be convenient to have a way to dynamically label them like this:

```
> ll <- list("1" = 2)
> ll
$`1`
[1] 2
```

But this is not working:

```
> ll <- list(as.character(1) = 2)
Error: unexpected '=' in "ll <- list(as.character(1) ="
```

Neither is this:

```
> ll <- list(paste(1) = 2)
Error: unexpected '=' in "ll <- list(paste(1) ="
```

Why is that? Both *paste()* and *as.character()* are returning "1".

Comment: `list(\`11\` = 10)` and similar. As far as why...I guess because the left hand side of `=` is not evaluated in that context. If you want to assign names "programmatically", have a look at `setNames`

Comment: I understand that one could use 'names' (or 'setNames'), if you have a vector with names at hand. I was just wondering why it is impossible to use 'paste' or 'as.character' in this context.

Comment: @user2870422 Because that's not how named parameters work. If you run `myfun(a=b)`. You don't want that to be have differently whether or not you've defined a variable named `a`. In order to "return" `"i"` the statement has to be evaluated as Frank mentioned. Parameter names are not evaluated.

Comment: @user2870422 Fair enough. Someone else may have a more technical explanation than I can muster. I have a couple of ugly workarounds I might throw into an answer, anyways. I'm afraid this is just an ugly feature of the language.

Comment: @MrFlick "Parameter names are not evaluated"
Thanks, that was sort of what I expected as an answer. It's good to know about these basic rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `paste(1)` is a function call that evaluates to a string, not a string itself.

The [The R Language Definition](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html) says this:

```
Each argument can be tagged (tag=expr), or just be a simple expression. 
It can also be empty or it can be one of the special tokens ‘...’, ‘..2’, etc.

A tag can be an identifier or a text string.
```

Thus, tags can't be expressions.

However, if you want to set names (which are just an attribute), you can do so with structure, eg

```
> structure(1:5, names=LETTERS[1:5])
A B C D E 
1 2 3 4 5
```

Here, `LETTERS[1:5]` is most definitely an expression.

Comment: Good find. Do you know what is meant by "an identifier" (as distinct from "a text string")?

Comment: See Section 10.3.2 - Identifiers of the link.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Now I'll starting (ab)using syntax like `assign("x$a",1)` as in the examples.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is simply to use integers as names (as in the question title), you can type them in with backticks or single- or double-quotes (as the OP already knows). They are converted to characters, since all names are characters in R.

---

I can't offer a deep technical explanation for why your later code fails beyond "the left-hand side of `=` is not evaluated in that context (of enumerating items in a list)". Here's one workaround:

```
mylist <- list()
mylist[[paste("a")]] <- 2 
mylist[[paste("b")]] <- 3
mylist[[paste("c")]] <- matrix(1:4,ncol=2)
mylist[[paste("d")]] <- mean
```

And here's another:

```
library(data.table)
tmp <- rbindlist(list( 
    list(paste("a"), list(2)), 
    list(paste("b"), list(3)),
    list(paste("c"), list(matrix(1:4,ncol=2))),
    list(paste("d"), list(mean))
))

res <- setNames(tmp$V2,tmp$V1)

identical(mylist,res) # TRUE
```

The drawbacks of each approach are pretty serious, I think. On the other hand, I've never found myself in need of richer naming syntax.